# How can I find the rotation of a quad in 3D?

Tags: math, 3d, vector, geometry, rotation

I have coordinates for 4 vectors defining a quad and another one for it's normal. I am trying to get the rotation of the quad. I get good results for rotation on X and Y just using the normal, but I got stuck getting the Z, since I've used just 1 vector.

Here's my basic test using [Processing](http://processing.org/) and [toxiclibs](http://toxiclibs.org/)([Vec3D](https://dev.postspectacular.com/docs/core/toxi/geom/Vec3D.html) and [heading methods](https://dev.postspectacular.com/docs/core/toxi/geom/Vec3D.html#headingXY%28%29)):

```
import toxi.geom.*;

Vec3D[] face = {new Vec3D(1.1920928955078125e-07, 0.0, 1.4142135381698608),new Vec3D(-1.4142134189605713, 0.0, 5.3644180297851562e-07),new Vec3D(-2.384185791015625e-07, 0.0, -1.4142135381698608),new Vec3D(1.4142136573791504, 0.0, 0.0),};
Vec3D n = new Vec3D(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

print("xy: " + degrees(n.headingXY())+"\t");
print("xz: " + degrees(n.headingXZ())+"\t");
print("yz: " + degrees(n.headingYZ())+"\n");

println("angleBetween x: " + degrees(n.angleBetween(Vec3D.X_AXIS)));
println("angleBetween y: " + degrees(n.angleBetween(Vec3D.X_AXIS)));
println("angleBetween z: " + degrees(n.angleBetween(Vec3D.X_AXIS)));

println("atan2 x: " + degrees(atan2(n.z,n.y)));
println("atan2 y: " + degrees(atan2(n.z,n.x)));
println("atan2 z: " + degrees(atan2(n.y,n.x)));
```

And here is the output:

```
xy: 90.0    xz: 0.0 yz: 90.0
angleBetween x: 90.0
angleBetween y: 90.0
angleBetween z: 90.0
atan2 x: 0.0
atan2 y: 0.0
atan2 z: 90.0
```

How can I get the rotation(around it's centre/normal) for Z of my quad ?

Comment: @belisarius. I've added the output. I made tests with coordinates of a plane rotated just on X by 10 degrees, then just on Y by 10 degrees, then just on Z by 10 degrees. For X and Y I got the right angles in the output.

Comment: Not wishing to be obtuse, but what does "rotation of a quad" even mean? Rotation of what, to where? (Also, your 3 `println("ab...")` lines repeat the same axis each time.)

Comment: @walkytalky If I say 'plane' some people might think it's an infinite plane. Others might think it's a rectangle, but it could be an arbitrary quadrilateral. In this example it's a square rotated at 45 degrees on the X axis. I've fixed the println("ab...") print, thanks for mentioning that. So, If I have the coordinates for 4 planes of a quadrilateral and it's normal, how can I determine the quadrilateral's rotation ? Does this make sense ? Sorry if I'm being vague, let me know what I can do to make things clear.

Comment: Without knowing the starting position of the quad, it doesn't realy make sense to talk about its rotation. Also do you mean rotation about the origin, or rotation combined with translation?

Comment: What @Michael said. A rotation is a transformation from one thing (say vector) to another. We need to know the start and end to be able to figure out what the rotation(s) would be. (Also, you fixed the `println("at...")` *labels*, but the `println("ab...")` *axes* are still all `Vec3D.X_AXIS`. Notice that the corresponding outputs are all `90.0`.)

Comment: @walkytalky Thanks for pointing that out. I've made slight amends. By "rotation of a quad" I mean rotating 4 vectors that are in the same plane around their centre (which is the normal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. I am frankly still not really clear on what it is you're looking for, but let me try to clarify the problem and then address my best guess as to what you really want and see if that helps.

As mentioned in the comment thread, a rotation is a **transformation** that maps one set of stuff (eg, vectors **A**, **B**, **C**...) to a different set of stuff (**A'**, **B'**, **C'**...). We can fully define this transformation in terms of an angle (call it θ) and an axis of rotation we'll call **R**.

Note that **R** is not a vector, it is a *line*. That means it has a *location* as well as a direction -- it is anchored somewhere in space -- and so you need either two points or a point and a direction vector to define it. For simplicity we might assume that the anchor point is the origin (0,0,0), since the question talks about the major axes X, Y and Z. In general, however, this need not be the case - if you want to determine rotation about arbitrary lines you will usually need to translate everything first so that the axis passes through the origin. (If all you care about is the *orientation* of your objects, rather than its position, then you can probably gloss over this issue.)

Given a start position **A**, end position **A'** and an axis **R**, it is conceptually straightforward to determine the angle θ (or *an* angle θ, since rotation is periodic and there are infinitely many θs that will take **A** to **A'**), though it can be a little fiddly for general **R**. In the simplest case, where **R** is one of the major axes, you can do something like this (for **R** = **Z**):

```
theta0 = atan2(A.x, A.y);
theta1 = atan2(A_prime.x, A_prime.y);
theta = theta1 - theta0;
```

In any case, it looks from your code as if you have the tools to do this already -- I'm not familiar with **toxiclibs**, but I would imagine the `Vec3D` `angleBetween` method ought to take you *most* of the way to the answer you want.

However, that presupposes that you know **A**, **A'** and **R**, and it seems like this is the real sticking point with your question. In the first place, you mention only a single set of points, defining an arbitrary quad. In the second, you talk about the normal as defining the centre of rotation. Both of these indicate that you haven't properly specified the problem.

As I have repeated tediously several times, a rotation is *from* one thing *to* another. A single set of quad vertices may define either the first state or the second, but not both (unless θ is 0, in which case the question is trivial). If you want to determine "the rotation of the quad", you need also to say "from an earlier position P" or "to a subsequent position Q", which you have not done.

Given that the *particular* quad in question is a **square**, you might think that there's an intuitive other position involved, to wit: with the sides axis-aligned. And we can indeed rather easily determine the angle of rotation required to get to that orientation, *if we can assume that the quad is a rectangle*:

```
// A and B are adjacent corners of the square
// B - A is the direction of the edge joining them
// theta is the angle between that side and the X axis
// (rotating by -theta around Z should align the square)
theta = atan2(B.x - A.x, B.y - A.y);
```

**But**, you made a point of stating that you might be looking at any arbitrary quad, for which there would  be no "natural" base position to compare against. And even in the square case it is frankly not good practice to presume a baseline without explicitly declaring it.

Which brings us back to my original question: what do you *mean*? If you can actually pin that down properly I suspect you will find the problem itself relatively easy to solve.

---

**EDIT:** Based on your comments below, what you really want to do is to find a rotation that aligns your quad with one of the major planes. This is equivalent to rotating the quad's normal to align with the axis perpendicular to that plane: eg, to get the quad parallel to the XY plane, align its normal with the Z axis.

This can notionally be done with a single rotation about some calculated axis, but in practice you will decompose it into two rotations about major axes. The first rotates about the target axis until the vector is in the plane containing that axis and one of the others; then rotate around the third axis to get the normal to its final alignment. A verbal description is inevitably clunky, so let's formalise a bit:

Let's say you have a planar object **Q**, with vertices {**v1**, **v2**, **v3**, ...} (in your quad case there will be four of these, but it could be any number as long as all the points are coplanar), with unit normal **n** = (x y z)<sup>T</sup>. For the sake of explanation, let's arbitrarily assume that we want to align the object with the XY plane, and hence to rotate **n** to the Z axis -- the process would be essentially the same for XZ/Y or YZ/X.

Rotate around Z to get **n** into the XZ plane. We can calculate the angle required like this:

```
theta1 = -atan2(x,y);
```

However, we only need the sine and cosine to build a rotation matrix, and we can calculate these directly  without knowing the angle:

```
hypoXY = sqrt(x*x + y*y);
c1 = x/hypoXY;
s1 = y/hypoXY;
```

(Obviously, if `hypoXY` is 0 this fails, but in that case **n** is already aligned with Z.)

Our first rotation matrix **R1** looks like this:

```
[  c1  s1  0 ]
[ -s1  c1  0 ]
[  0   0   1 ]
```

Next, rotate around Y to get **n** parallel to Z. Note that the previous rotation has moved x to a new position x' = sqrt(x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup>), so we need to account for this in calculating our second angle:

```
theta2 = -atan2(z, sqrt(x*x + y*y));
```

Again, we don't actually need theta2. And because we defined **n** to be a unit vector, our next calculations are easy:

```
c2 = z;
s2 = hypoXY;
```

Our second rotation matrix **R2** looks like this:

```
[ c2  0  -s2 ]
[ 0   1   0  ]
[ s2  0   c2 ]
```

Compose the two together to get **R** = **R2.R1**:

```
[  c2c1   c2s1  -s2  ]
[ -s1     c1     0   ]
[  s2c1   s2s1  c2   ]
```

If you apply this matrix to **n**, you *should* get the normal aligned with the Z axis. (If not, check the signs first -- this is all a bit *back of an envelope* and I could easily have got some of the directions wrong. I don't have time to code it up and check right now, but will try to give it a go later. I'll also try to look over your sketch code then.)

Once that works, apply the same transformation to all the points in your object **Q** and it should become parallel to (although likely offset from) the XY plane.

Comment: Very well explained. Thank you! I think Vec3D's angleBetween is something like acos(firstVector.dotProduct(secondVector)). The "from rotation" will be rotation of the quad and the "to rotation" will be whatever rotation will align the quad with a plane(xz for example). What I'm trying to do is to rotate a quad with 3d dimensions so it is aligned with an axis and one dimension could be dropped/the quad could be drawn in 2d(flat, no rotations). I did using a rectangle rotated 10 degrees on X, then used the X rotation determined using atan2(z,y).

Comment: Then I created a rotation matrix at -10 degrees and muliplied it to the quad points. The quad was 'flat' again. Repeated the test only with the y axis and it worked. Repeated the test with the z axis and it failed. Also, when I used coordinates of a rectangle rotated 10 on x and 10 on y for the quad, then tried to remove the rotations, it failed. I imagine the major problem is finding the rotation on Z. Sorry, I'm horrible at explaining things sometimes. Let me know what I need to detail.

Comment: @George Z rotation should not be materially different from X and Y, so you are doing something wrong - check for trivial coding errors like that persistent `Vec3D.X_AXIS` in your question code. On the 10 x, 10 y question, note that sequences of rotations are *not commutative* - you need to pay attention to the order you apply them. I'll try to give a fuller answer later, but right now I'm off to play in the sunshine...

Comment: I've uploaded a sketch here(http://lifesine.eu/processing/RotationMatrix/RemoveRotation/). Again, let me know if the syntax confusing. I have coordinates for 4 quads and their normals: a square rotated at 10 degrees on x, one rotated at 10 on y and another one rotated at 10 on z...10/10/10/...nice and sunny...the last face/quad/square is rotated at 10 on x and 10 on y. If you press 'c' in the sketch, the squares/quads will be cycled. face_rx_10 (face with rotation x of 10 degrees) is rotated fine, so is face_ry_10. face_rz_10 fails...and if I have face_rxy also fails in my approach

Comment: @George Having looked at your code: (1) your "rotated around Z" quad is actually around Y -- note the normal; (2) that one won't go straight because the normal is already aligned (I think it actually flips over, so you see the quad reflected) -- if you want to orient the square to the other axes too, you need to look at the edges rather than the normal, but this brings us back to the issue of "natural" orientation; (3) you're treating the rotations as commutative, which is why your X+Y version doesn't work. See my edit from this morning for relevant info, and google "Euler Angles" for more.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the rotation matrix for the z axis

cos(theta)    sin(theta)  0

-sin(theta)  cos(theta)  0

0                                        0           1

- your vector

the result is the rotated vector

Comment: right, that's a rotation matrix, I multiply it to my vector to get the rotated vector. I'm looking for something like the reverse. I have 4 vectors(defining a quadrilateral) and a normal, can I determine the rotation the z axis from that ?

Comment: what I need is the opposite...I have a rotated vector(4 of them and a normal actually) and I want to determine the rotation(around the centre) on the z axis of the quad/plane defined by these 4 vectors.

Comment: you can solve that if you have the old vector, by solvong three equations with only one variable

Comment: current_vector=matrix*old_vector  gives three equations so you can solve that if you have the old vector, by solving three equations with only one variable